# While running the project, I am getting an exception as System.InvalidOperationException: 'The host has not yet started'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am facing this issue only for the particular repo as when I debug i found out that the version of the Azure core tool is older, I updated my Core Tools version from 4.0.4544 to 4.0.4915(x64)

[image]

Then after restart and deleting all the temp files when I run my application same error is thrown, and what I found the version is not updated , i check but couldn't find the older version core tool, all i can see is i have only one Azure core tool version which is 4.0.4915(x64)
So, is there any way to found out from where the application is getting the older version of Azure core tool in my local mechine.

I have deleted, and updated the version and also clear the temp file and restart my machine.

The running application is somehow showing the older version of core tool still now.

I checked everything launchSetting.json, jobHost.cs, local.setting.json, startup.cs
Every thing i correctly written.
As i checked with my buddies project only thing which is different is the Azure core tool version,

how to remove the default Azure core tool version and from where?

Answer (score 0):

The terms on the Azure Functions Versions are:

1. Azure Functions Core Tools Version (V4)
2. Azure Functions Core Tools Versioned Commits Version (Such as `4.0.4544`, `4.0.4653`)

The Latest Version in Azure Functions Core Tools is v4 in the generic View.
Some patch updates will be done to the V4 version of AFCT regarding the existing feature breaking changes or adding the new features to it.

The earlier version you have is `4.0.4544` released on May 2022 with the following updates:
[image]

As you have updated to `4.0.4915` which is the latest patch update version to the v4 Azure Functions core tools, found in the official release GitHub [Repos](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/tags) of AFCT.

---

When I run the Azure Function from the local IDE, I have got the below versions in the console:

[image]

[image]

From the above practical, we can say that the latest patch version of v4 Azure Functions Core Tools is `4.0.4915` but the AFCT Commit Version in the local is `4.0.4653` because the commit version of `4.0.4915` is not yet came to the Windows X64 OS Machine which is my current Machine Configuration.

[image]

Whereas the Core Tools Commit Patch Version `4.0.4653` is compatible with all the OS and bit-Configuration such Win X64, etc. So, this version `4.0.4653` is the current AFCT Commit Patch Version running the Azure Functions Host Runtime locally.

**Note:** You can check this path for the Commit Patch Versions of AFCT v4 in the `C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools`.